# Keep reference of an activity in the companion object

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 2 activities: MainActivity and MySecondActivity.
I start MySecondActivity, but while I'm working in it, I receive a callback from an external library in MainActivity. This callback should update some information in MySecondActivity.

Question: Can I keep a reference of MySecondActivity in MainActivity in order to update it later ?

Basically it would be like this:

```
val mySecondIntent = Intent(applicationContext, MySecondActivity::class.java)
startActivity(mySecondIntent)

(...)

fun MyCallBackFunction(newInfo: Integer)
mySecondIntent.updateMyInfo(newInfo) <-- here I cannot access "MySecondIntent"
```

I tried to store the reference of mySecondIntent in the companion object but I could not make it work.

Do you have any suggestion ?

Thank you !

Comment: `MySecondActivity in MainActivity` only if you want crashes after process death :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. Don't let any activity keeps the other activity reference, it's not the best practice.

**Suggestion**

If the callback you receive has impact on multiple activities, then make it global. I usually create a singleton manager class for handling each global event's logic that may have impact on many places in the app. Anywhere in your app need to listen for the event, register the event to the manager.

For example, my `AppLocationManager` is a singleton class, responsible for making gps refresh and other location stuff. When location change, fire events to all registered listeners. In your case, both MainActivity and SecondActivity knows the changes and update itself, remember to unregister the listener in activity onDestroy, or you will have a memory leak.

**Workaround for quick implementation**

If you still want to keep the activity reference for quick modification, which is not recommended, use `WeakReference`

Store a `WeakReference` of `MySecondActivity` as a static global variable:

```
public static WeakReference<Activity> mTmpAtivity
```

Unlike default `StrongReference`, this variable will release the instance if the activity is GC so it's memory safe.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. I will keep with good practice and use a singleton for my callback. But your additional information about WeakReference is also very interesting, I didn't know it was possible to do it.

Comment: Glad I can help